# how to add a row in a datagridview via other form using C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm stuck in a problem in windown form (C#). I have MainUI form consist of a DataGridView, that contains data in my database and a button called BtnRegister. And I have Register form containing some TextBoxs, CheckBoxs... and a confirm button. When I click BtnRegister, Register form is shown and I can input data by typing in textboxs, ... and confirm data inputed by clicking confirm button. The problem is that I dont known how to add a new row into DataGridView in MainUI form by clicking confirm button in Register form. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J52ta.png)

Sorry, my English is not good. But I have a significant hope that some one can help to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: You need a reference to the other form, often passed out in the show&constructor and to make the dgv public. There are a million duplicates around..Several ways are in the link,

Answer (score -1):

Just observe the dialog result in your main form. For example:

```
If (register.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    dataGridView.Add();
    // do something
}
```